# How do I sync a subset of tables between two databases on the differnet mysql database server?

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I have the main MySQL database which has the following columns in one of the car table:

```
 +---------------+-----------------+------+
 |carId          |name             |model |   
 +---------------+-----------------+------+
 |1              |ford             |focus |
 |2              |Toyota           |Yaris |
 +---------------+-----------------+------+
```

Here is what I looking to achieve:

I want to create the new Database in some other msql server and want to create the same table as above and want to add following columns in the new car table

```
+---------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+------------+
|carId          |name             |model       |make       |workHistory |
+---------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+------------+
|1              |ford             |focus       |2001       |yes         |
|2              |Toyota           |Yaris       |2002       |no          |
+---------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

1. I want the new Database table to get data for `carId`, `name` and `model` columns from the main sql database car table.  And would only like to insert data for columns (`make`, `workHistory`) in new database car table  myself. So this new car table will combine data from the main MySQL database and new Database.
2. If there is any change in main database car table, I want those changes to be sync with car table in new database. For example if we deleted the ID in main database car table, it should be deleted from the new car table as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about replication - just use an additional table:

```
CREATE TABLE car_more (
    carId INT NOT NULL,
    make INT,
    workHistory
    PRIMARY KEY (carId)
);
```

If the databases you refer to (do you mean databases or tables?) are on seperate instance of mysql, then use the federated engine to provide remote access to the existing table. Then you can access the data using....

```
SELECT a.carId, a.name, a.model, b.make, b.workHistory
FROM car a
LEFT JOIN car_more b
ON (a.carId=b.carId);
```

If they are on the same mysq instance, then just prefix the table names with database names:

```
SELECT a.carId, a.name, a.model, b.make, b.workHistory
FROM maindb.car a
LEFT JOIN alternatedb.car_more b
ON (a.carId=b.carId);
```

(you could use mysql amster-master replication to maintain a local copy of the car table - but this is a lot more complicated)

Comment: Thanks symcbean, If the databases you refer to (do you mean databases or tables?) ?

Comment: Thanks symcbean, Yes thats correct the databases are on seperate instance of mysql . Just to clarify , can I use federated engine  to triger the changes to be updated on the altername databse(alternatedb.car) if there were any changes on main database(maindb.car)

Comment: Yes once configured a federated table behaves just the same as if it were local (except that more than one DBMS instance can read/write it)

Answer (score 1):

First, the database design.  *Why* do you only want the `make` and `workHistory` columns in the slave database?  It looks to me like they are related and in a one-to-one relationship with the data in the other columns.  Logically, the data belongs together... why separate it?

It will be easier on the database management side to have one, canonical copy of all the data that gets replicated.

Second, are you intending on *writing* to the second database or only reading from it?  Read-only is much easier to manage.

---

Assuming you want a read-only slave, set up replication as per normal and make sure permissions on the slave only allow `SELECT`.

If you don't want the extra columns in the main table, create a second table with `carId`, `model` and `workHistory` and create a [view](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Introduction_to_MySQL_Views) that joins them on the `carId`.

---

If you want to write to the slave, you will need multi-master replication or something similar.  It's more complicated.  I'll add more if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks mate, The Reason I want (make& work history) columns in the slave database is because I have 2 departments who will be adding car information on 2 separate databases ,main database has already up and having CAR ID and Car name,car MAKE information ,which is managed by department1 . Now we want Database for Department 2 ,who will be adding extra information (Make& work history )  from data taken from the Car table In the main database. 
Continue to nex comment

Comment: Department1 database is the main database where they will be adding or changing Car make and car name information, that is the reason Department 2 database relay on the data from department 1 database . Reason we dont want to add car name and make information Manaully to the department 2 database as we are wanting to Sync data from Deparment 1 database .

Comment: any solution you can Recommend